# Google Materialize not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, materialize

IE is used still by 15.5% of the web users so I would like to support it and Materialize is not supported in IE 7.  However, Im testing it in latest browser.

The problem area of the code is that the materialize.js is not working. Specifically this part:

```
/** Navbar mobile collapse **/
$('.button-collapse').sideNav();
```

Also not working is the dropdown menus, so definetly a JS problem.

Here are the steps I have tried so far:

1. Putting jQuery above the materialize css and js files.  I had some functionality brought back by putting at the top of the page rather than the bottom.
2. Used an Async load an example is given below:

   ```
       jQl.loadjQ('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'); Ql.loadjQ('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js');
   ```
3. Tried to use a materialize hack:

   ```
     (function($){
     $(function(){
        $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
     }); // end of document ready
     })(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
   ```

If you can help me get unstuck, much appreciated.   Otherwise works fine in Chrome so unlikely to be a coding error.  ***UPDATE works in firefox but not opera.

Answer (score 0):

"Hallo Leute",

I fixed the problem by manually uploading the js and css files to the web host environment.  Now it works in IE just need to test Opera.

Great stuff critically said